# Kernel memory allocator patch

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, memory, patch

Is there any patch for Linux kernel to use different memory allocators, such as [ned allocator](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/) or [TLSF allocator](http://rtportal.upv.es/rtmalloc/)?

Comment: Maybe you should add some rationale for why this would be a good thing to do? If such a patch exists and hasn't already made its way into the kernel there's probably a good reason.

Comment: I don't have any rationale as for linux kernel itself, but I'am developing multicore scalable real-time application using those allocator, and I see performance is better and scalable to the number of cores, so I'am asking is there any patch for linux kernel to be used those allocators, so my question is same as yours, if it hasn't ported to linux kernel, what's the reasons?

Comment: I think you should simple investigate how Linux kernel does memory allocation and perhaps you will understand more about it. There are some fundamental differences compared to memory allocation in user-level programs, since there is no underlying OS to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The allocators you mention are *userspace* allocators, entirely different to kernel allocators. Perhaps some of the underlying concepts could be used in the kernel, but it would have to be implemented from scratch.

The kernel already has 3 allocators, SLAB, SLUB, SLOB, (and there was/is SLQB). SLUB in particular is designed to work well on multi-CPU systems.

As always if you have ideas on how to improve the kernel, your specific suggestions, preferably in the form of patches, are welcome on LKML :-)